# Integrate of HypergeometricPFQ gives the wrong result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

Good morning,
I computed the following integral using Integrate in version 12.2 and it gives the wrong result. Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong? Here is the integral:

```
Integrate[(
 n (1 + n) (1 + 2 n) (3 + 
    2 n) (-HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1 - 2 n, 4 + 2 n}, {2, 3, 3}, 1] +
     t HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1 - 2 n, 4 + 2 n}, {2, 3, 3}, t]) Log[
   t])/(-1 + t), {t, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n > 0]
```

the result is

```
-(1/6) n (1 + n) (1 + 2 n) (3 + 2 n) \[Pi]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 
   1 - 2 n, 4 + 2 n}, {2, 3, 3}, 1]
```

For instance, this result is $-\frac{10 \pi ^2}{3} $ for $n=1$.
However if I set $n=1$ inside Integrate or use NIntegrate i get $-17.5$, which is the correct result. Why is there such a difference? Here is the code

```
NIntegrate[((
   n (1 + n) (1 + 2 n) (3 + 
      2 n) (-HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1 - 2 n, 4 + 2 n}, {2, 3, 3}, 
        1] + t HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1 - 2 n, 4 + 2 n}, {2, 3, 3}, 
        t]) Log[t])/(-1 + t)) /. n -> 1, {t, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}]
```

and

```
Integrate[(
  n (1 + n) (1 + 2 n) (3 + 
     2 n) (-HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1 - 2 n, 4 + 2 n}, {2, 3, 3}, 
       1] + t HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1 - 2 n, 4 + 2 n}, {2, 3, 3}, 
       t]) Log[t])/(-1 + t) /. n -> 1, {t, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers && n > 0]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A possible bug. In my version (12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)), the first integral returns unevaluated, and the second two return -17.5 and -35/2.  What version are you using?

Comment: This returns unevaluated in 12.3.1 on windows 10. May be there was a bug and WRI fixed it?  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMD5x.png) it is always best to use latest version of software.

Comment: This also returns `-35/2` in MM 12.3.1 for Mac OS (ARM).

Comment: Remains unevaluated for me in `"12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"` as well as in V12.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

As n is integer you can try

```
Table[Integrate[(n (1 + n) (1 + 2 n) (3 + 2 n) 
(-HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1 - 2 n, 4 + 2 n}, {2, 3, 3}, 1] + 
t HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1 - 2 n, 4 + 2 n}, {2, 3, 3}, t]) 
Log[t])/(-1 + t), {t, 0, 1}], {n, 1, 10}]
```

for n up to 10 or higher.

The result -10Pi^2/3 for n=1 is just the integral over the term with the first Hypergeometric.